# XPath AND operator with text() sequence

Tags: xpath

If the XML is defined by the following:

```
<xs:complexType name="Whatever" ....>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Tag" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complextType>
```

a document can contain:

```
<ns:Whatever>
  <ns:Tag>hello</ns:Tag>
  <ns:Tag>Peter</ns:Tag>
  <ns:Tag>how are you</ns:Tag>
</ns:Watever>
```

or it could contain:

```
<ns:Whatever>
  <ns:Tag>hello</ns:Tag>
</ns:Watever>
```

How does one write an XPath expression to find XML `Whatever` elements a union of `Tag` elements comparing the `text()` with an `AND` operator?

Writing `/ns:Whatever[ns:Tag/text() = ('hello','Peter','how are you')]` matches both above documents.  I want to only match when the text of `Tag` is equal to `'hello'` AND `'Peter'` AND `'how are you'`.

Comment: I don't know what this is, but it is definitely not a valid .xml file. If you fix it then we could answer your question. A tag , with or without a namespace must close with the exact same tag.

Comment: Assume your are refering to the misspelled "ns:Watever" which should have ben "ns:Whatever".

Comment: I edited your post because it was completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully your .xml contains typos.

You need the or operator not the and :

```
<xsl:value-of select="/ns:Whatever/ns:Tag[ . = 'hello' or . = 'Peter' or . = 'how are you']"/>
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  Or as an operator matches even Tag elements with single entries.

Comment: @MatthewYoung What would you like to match? I am confused by your description.

Comment: Take the XML document fragment above with the 3 Tag elements.  There is a common Tag 'hello' with the fragment with only 1 Tag.  Using the "or" operator does just that, it returns both fragments because each have a Tag with 'hello' as a textual value.  I want an "and" style operation to match a fragment when there Tag elements that equal several values.